# Should I use the bool tool after I have already started sculpting?

Tags: mesh, modifiers, objects, workflow, sculpting

I'm defiantly a noob to Blender and I am very cautious.
I know that that one of the general work flows for creating a character consist of forming spheres to create a base mesh, then joining the spheres together, and then sculpting to add further detail and etc. And currently that is my main approach. But I was wondering about what would happen if you bool tooled everything together, then sculpt, then bool tooled a new mesh to the sculpt. Can you actually do that? Or would it mess up the mesh somehow? Does it even matter?

Comment: I think the spheres way is how simpsons are drawn. I can only imgagine using dyntopo to connect spheres, anything else I would suggest roughly model the shape you're after and then start sculpting. I've used boolean to insert feet into an irregular model, but that was dyntopo and I didn't care how unclean the seams were.

Comment: Yes you can use boolean to add some shapes to your object and sculpt again

Comment: Thanks everyone for the responses!